# How do i detect white space or numbers when using UTF8CPP?

Tags: c++, unicode

This is my code:

```
std::vector<std::string> InverseIndex::getWords(std::string line)
{
  std::vector<std::string> words;

  char* str = (char*)line.c_str();
  char* end = str + strlen(str) + 1;
  unsigned char symbol[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};

  while( str < end ){
    utf8::uint32_t code = utf8::next(str, end);
    if(code == 0) continue;
    utf8::append(code, symbol);
    // TODO detect white spaces or numbers.
    std::string word = (const char*)symbol;
    words.push_back(word);
  }

  return words;
}
```

---

```
Input : "你 好 啊 哈哈 1234"

Output : 
你
??
好
 ??
啊
 ??
哈
哈
 ??
1??
2??
3??
4??

Expected output : 
你
好
啊
哈
哈
```

Is there anyway to skip the white space or numbers , thanks?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of UTF8CPP

Answer (score 2):

UTF8-CPP is nothing more than a tool for encoding and decoding strings into/outof UTF-8. Classification of Unicode codepoints is *well* outside the scope of that tool. You'll need to use a serious localization tool like Boost.Locale or ICU for that.

Answer (score -1):

UTF-8 is "ASCII compatible" in the following sense:

If one of the bytes of the encoded string is equal to ASCII value - such as space, new line, or digits 0-9, this means that it is not a part of encoded sequence longer than a byte. It is actually this very character.

This means, that you can do isdigit() on a byte in UTF8 string as if it was an ASCII string, and it is guaranteed to work correctly.

For more information, see http://utf8everywhere.org the section on search.